# jQuery updating DOM while dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery-ui sortable, and my idea is to apply sorting on items that appears while scrolling.
I am using the following code:

```
  var gridTop = 0,
        gridBottom = container.outerHeight();
   $('#play-list').on('scroll', function () {
        $('#play-list li:not(.selectableHide):not(.sorting-initialize)').each(function () {
            var thisTop = $(this).offset().top;
            if (thisTop >= gridTop && (thisTop + $(this).height()) <= gridBottom) {
                if ($(this).attr('data-hour') != houseScope) {
                    houseScope= $(this).attr('data-hour');
                    console.log(houseScope);
                }
                $(this).addClass("sorting-initialize");
                var waitInterval = setInterval(() => {
                    timeout += timeout;
                    if (timeout == 300) {
                        clearInterval(waitInterval);
                        $('#play-list .sortable').sortable('refresh');
                        timeout = 10;
                    }
                }, timeout);
            }
        });
    });
```

I've added a log to check the hour i'm currently at in the playlist while scrolling.
Everything works fine when simply scrolling, but when I drag an element & scroll while dragging it, I can see that the hour still changes correctly, but "sorting-initialize" is not being added.

EDIT:
After further debugging, I see now that the problem is not that the class is not being added, but the DOM not being updated while dragging. I can see in Chrome's console (inspect element is open) that the class are being added, but the DOM is "frozen" in it's previous state untill drag is over, so I can't drop the element on the new sortable elements. Any solutions for it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the scrolling element is 'container' and not 'body' ?

Comment: yes, it's a scrollable div inside the page

Answer (score 0):

jQuery works with loaded DOM. If you want to use an 'on' event with dynamic data, you must anchor it to an existing DOM element.

Try using

```
$('body').on('scroll', '#play-list', function () {...
```

You can change the 'body' tag with the parent container ID of the '#play-list' div

Comment: '#play-list' is an existing DOM element. Anyway I tried using 'on' on the parent container, same problem here